# .net core 2.0 Entity Framework - Add table relationship at db level and update model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm working on an application who implements .net core 2.0 with Entity Framework.

I have generated the model by scaffolding the existent db using package manager console.

Now I have manually edited the database by adding a missing relationship between two tables.

What is the best way to update the model?

In this moment I'm deleting all the model files and I run the scaffolding command each time...

How to avoid this ?

Thanks to support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add the missing virtual fields to the objects.

If the columns have matching names, you can simply add them directly:

```
class Customer {
    public int CustomerId {get;set;} // PK that was already there

    // new navigation property
    public virtual ICollection<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}

class Account {
    public int AccountId {get;set;} 

    // new FK
    public int CustomerId { get;set; }
    // new navigation property
    public virtual Customer Customer {get;set;} 
}
```

In case you have multiple fks to the same table, or names don't match, you may have to add some code to the `OnModelCreating` method on your DbContext.

The simpler way to see how this is done is to regenerate once your code with your tool and compare the old one with a tool like WinMerge. EF Core is much simpler than EF6, once you understand the idea you'll never have to use these tools again. I hand code all my entities and I find it much easier than using these tools.